# A-Frame Loader for STL File

Tags: aframe, stl-format

I'm trying to include a STL file like a GLTF object in my A-Frame page, but I'm not making progress. I don't understand why the file doesn't work in a similar manner. Here is my code for the working page on Glitch with a GLTF file and a non-working one with the STL file. All object files are hosted on GitHub.

glitch.com/edit/#!/dramatic-hornet

(below is the non-working code excerpt copied from Glitch)

```
<a-scene>
   <a-assets>
     <a-asset-item id="object" src="https://github.com/rschildge/models/raw/master/NinjaSpinner.stl"></a-asset-item>
   </a-assets>

 <a-entity model="#object" position="0 0 -4" scale=".1 .1 .1"></a-entity>
 <!-- <a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9" shadow></a-box>-->
  <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4" shadow></a-plane>
  <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
</a-scene>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know, a-frame's core doesn't have any loader for the `.stl` format.

There is a pretty recent community-made [loader](https://github.com/darkwave/aframe-stl-model-component), be sure to check it out.
If it won't work, be sure to file an issue. If it works - give it a friendly star.

---

As for models in general, the a-frame team recommends the glTF format in the [docs](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/introduction/models.html#sidebar), as it is designed for webGL.

---

As for the `model=..` syntax, you need to use a loader component, either the `gltf-loader` (like you do on glitch), or any other, but it won't work just with a `model` keyword

Comment: I got it working with your help, but note that the cdn in the README.md isn't working for the loader : <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-stl-model-component/dist/aframe-stl-model-component.min.js"></script> . I used https://rawgit.com/darkwave/aframe-stl-model-component/master/dist/aframe-stl-model-component.min.js . It also worked fine with https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.0/aframe.min.js